The end of risk-neutral valuation
Risk-neutral valuation grew out of BS constructing market-neutral portfolios of stocks hedged with options.  It was a portfolio management problem.  In less than a decade, pricing by arbitrage on a complete arbitrage-free market was invented and the corresponding math theory was constructed.
Derivatives in such market are redundant or, equivalently, perfectly illiquid: they are merely fast changing portfolios of tradeables.  In reality however, once derivatives become tradeable, they distort the completeness of the original market, becoming the first-class tradeables. In other words, skews and smiles and "instrument spreads" emerge. More and more complex risk-neutral dynamics are proposed to jointly explain observed prices of related systems of derivatives, but with the purpose of pricing unobserved exotics. But those exotics are then never traded at theoretical model values, introducing the next order of smiles and instrument spreads.
Is the solution to the virtuous cycle in breaking away from pricing using the risk-neutral approach, and going back to the original portfolio management view, only backed by something like reinforcement learning to arrive at the equilibrium price and risk = capital requirement?

In my (perhaps simplistic) view risk-neutral pricing is a paradigm, not a particular method and specifically that the price of a derivative is the price of its replicating portfolio. If you deviate from that there is (possibility of) arbitrage, which in any case will probably not last for very long. So no, I don't think the end of RN pricing is anytime soon, whatever method is used to arrive at the price.

I give it 10 years. Some forms of RN will only stay as, possibly, a quotation mechanism of liquid and listed or quasi-listed products, and the rest will be priced and hedged non-parametrically under the constraints on the expected ROI.
Thoughts?

10 years in finance is like a blink of an eye in finance in my experience. Therefore, I doubt anything changes. Exotics are all hedged using mostly vanillas. If you deviate from pricing you likely open arbitrage opportunities (or end up with teh same price anyways).

“hedged non-parametrically” good luck understanding where your PnL is coming from and managing cross-risks.
